# Getting GeoJSON to work?

Tags: openlayers, geojson, style

What am I missing, trying to get Geojson object to get passed with a style, but its not working and there is no console error as well. What do I do?

```
var olview = new ol.View({
  center: [0, 869099],
  zoom: 7,
  minZoom: 2,
  maxZoom: 20
})

myMap = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms',
        params: {'LAYERS': 'basemap', 'TILED': true },
        serverType: 'geoserver'
      })
})
/*`var myMap = new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    });`
*/
// assuming you want to try it without having geoserver, use this

var geoJsonObject = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -1.6149902343749998,
          6.118707747190845
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
};

var geojson = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geoJsonObject)
});

var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
          anchor: [0.5, 46],
          anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
          anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
          src: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v4.2.0/examples/data/icon.png'
        }))
      });

var geojsonVector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: geojsonVector,
  style: iconStyle
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [myMap, geojsonVector],
  view: olview
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The section

```
var geojsonVector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: geojsonVector,
  style: iconStyle
});
```

Sets the source of the layer geojsonVector  to geojsonVector (itself). This should be set to geojson instead.

Comment: so it should be the geojson object instead. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, assuming there is a json file with the features:

```
var sampleLayerSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  url: (basePath + '/data/sample_layer.json'), // url to your json
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
});
```

I've also tried readFeatures(), but I didn't get any features.